# Problem with debuging shared library in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

My project consists of several shared libraries and one executable. I tried to debug my code from shared library but debugger never stops on breakpoints and I get warnings for each breakpoint: "Breakpoint attribute Problem: Installation Failed.". Can someone explain me this problem or provide workaround for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you start the program (causing it to load the shared libraries) before trying to set the breakpoints?  If you did it the other way around (set breakpoints before starting the program), it's likely not to work because the shared library code hasn't been loaded.

Comment: but then the error (at least with gdb which is the default debugger in cdt) would be different. And anyway, gdb suggest remembering the breakpoint and activate it on library load

Comment: In my experience the feature of activating breakpoints on future shared library loading does not work reliably when debugging C++ in gdb.  I suggest again that you must start the program first then set the breakpoints.  If Eclipse doesn't have a "start" button other than the one that runs the whole program until completion, you could try setting a breakpoint in the first line of main() or using gdb directly (then you'd use the "start" command).

Comment: I am not the OP, btw. I also prefer this way, do it by `b main; run`. On Linux however it is not enough to start the program, a library actually is loaded on the first call to it so you need to step/run through the program until that

Answer (score 0):

don't know if this will help you, but after some struggle I gave up debugging in eclipse and moved to the good old gdb (which is the backend for eclipse debugging anyway) - it was annoyingly too slow. You get used to command line interface sooner that you expect, and it's fast, convenient, intuitive yet powerful. I like working with UI and IDE but not at any cost. gdb has several UI "wrappers", ddd is one the most populars but they are not perfect either.

As for shared libraries - if you try to set a breakpoint before the library is loaded gdb will issue a warning and suggest to remember it and activate on future load. Or you can step through the program until the library is loaded.